# Spark ALS transform performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a spark newbie. I'm using pyspark for ALS recommendation. The fitting takes few minutes and runs fairly quickly. However the model.transform function takes a long time and requires significantly more nodes in the cluster.

1. I was wondering if there are any optimization I can do to deal with the model.transform function?
2. What is the method used underneath? Is it just simple matrix multiplication? If so can't I use another matrix multiplication library just for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the essence of ALS algorithm is matrix multiplication.
First thing to check if you have this kind of warning in your log

```
15/06/15 11:17:36 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
15/06/15 11:17:36 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
15/06/15 11:17:36 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
15/06/15 11:17:36 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
```

If you do — you should probably add external linear algebra library as a dependency. Refer to this [guide](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java)

Comment: Nope, no warning

Comment: @user1871528 which version of Spark do you use? Do you use scala or python API?